# Which Dragon Ball Z fighters use weighted clothing?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

Which Dragon Ball Z fighters used with weighted clothing?

Comment: This [site](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Weighted_Clothing) lists pretty much all users.

Comment: This site is not for *guesses*, it's for concrete answers backed up by evidence. So @Turamarth's link would actually make an excellent answer.

Answer (score -2):

In the complete series on Dragon Ball Z only goku was shown who wears the weighted clothes. It was shown during the martial tournament when we wants to feel a bit relaxed against Tien (I think not sure). When he removes his shoes Tien got surprised by the weight of the shows first. It weighed like more than 100 kg of one shoe. Rest of the fighters were wearing normal light clothes. Considering Vegeta, he was a different case he never removed his armour.